# null pointer exception for BasicProgressBarUI.getPrefrerredSize

Tags: java, swing

I am getting the following exception when executing the `SaveDialog` class `setVisible(true`) line.

This program will kick off when user hits **save** button. Then it will display status dialog while trying to save serialized object data.

```
public class SaveController implements ActionListener,Serializable{
    private JButton = new JButton("Save");
    public SaveController(){
         saveButton.addActionListener(this);
    }
    actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       if(ae.getSource == saveButton){
             new saveDialog();
       }
    }
}

public saveDialog extends JDialog{
    public saveDialog(){

         SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new Runnabe()(
            public void run(){
                   // set up gui layout...add status lister
                   pack();
                   setVisible(true);// this is where it crashes
            }
         }
         SaveTask task = new SaveTask();
         task.addEventListener(this);
         task.execute()
     }
}

public class SaveTask extends SwingWorker<void,void>{

    public void doInBackground(){
        File f = new File("file");
        f.createNewFile();
        OutputStream file = new OutputStream("file");
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        output.writeobject(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting exception. But where?

Comment: Add stacktrace please

Comment: Sorry I thought typed in the exceptio! Null Pointer exception

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Here it null pointer excepiton in BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize line 820. I don't have the full stack trace but it starts from my code trying to do a setVisible(true) in the save dialog

Comment: Your posted code doesn't compile, so any runtime exception is from previously compiled classes; try clean & build and post the stacktrace.